# Aspnet boilerplate swagger internal server error?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, aspnetboilerplate, swashbuckle

I'm getting the following error in swagger using .net core, boilerplate framework.
I made the necessary configurations in 'Startup.cs'. I included Swagger in the project.
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package version:5.5.1
How can I solve this problem?

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'.

Comment: Can you show the class `Startup`?

Answer (score 0):

Startup.cs swagger configurations:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

  services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);
        });}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){

 app.UseSwagger();
        
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AbpZeroTemplate API V1");
        });  }
```